# A good image format converter invokable from .NET?

Tags: .net, image, image-processing, file-type

I'm looking for a tool that can eat as many image formats as possible and convert them to jpg, something like [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org) but that's designed for images.

I need it to be free (GPL is OK), preferrably open sourced.

### Update

As per image magick, is there a way to determine which image types are supported by [`Image.FromFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromfile.aspx)? So I'll make sure it tries to use the built-in image converter before it runs imagemagick.
Any other tips on cleaning imagemagick's leaks in .NET will be welcomed as well.

Comment: Are there many formats you want to support other than [the standard ones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, But I want to first use the built in converter, than use the alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is the most full-featured imaging library I know of, but it leaks memory terribly. If the command line isn't out of the question, you could pipe into Python's PIL?

Comment: `identify -list format` will show you all of the formats your system supports. Assuming proper library files, of course, it looks like ImageMagick runs the gamut; it certainly handles every format I've ever come across. As for addressing the memory problems, it seems destroying an image's reference and then manually invoking garbage collection is the most sure-fire approach.

Comment: Thanks. Mean while [I've found](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5.aspx#remarksToggle) the supported files by .NET, it looks like a static list. Anyway, can you please help in determining the differences between the different versions of ImageMagick (Q8/Q16)?

Comment: Ah, .NET's FromFile. Assuming you want maximum format support, it'd likely be better to call into ImageMagick's command line interface; I'm not familiar enough with .NET to suggest the optimal way to go about this, but I imagine there's something akin to a system() function. As for Q8 and Q16, the latter is twice as resource-heavy because it supports 16-bit colors, which are necessary if you want to support RGBA images.

Comment: So it's not recommended on slow computers or what?